# IMPORTHTML function on google sheets

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets

I am trying to use the IMPORTHTML function on Google Sheets to create a table that I can refresh periodically. The code I am attempting to use is =IMPORTHTML("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.shtml","table",1), to try and get the table that says "Team Batting." However, when I do this, it gives me an error that says "Formula parse error." What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The table you want is table 10. Try this:

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.baseball-reference.com/teams/BOS/2018.shtml","table",10)
```